# EWDK Can't find SDK files?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, wdk

- VS2019
- SDK 19041 installed
- WDK 19041 installed
- SDK 22000 installed
- WDK 22000 installed

At this point one can't go back to building with WDK 19041 using Visual Studio because WDK 22000 has become the WDK used by Visual Studio.

I have the EWDK 19041 iso.

1. Mounted the iso
2. Command Prompt elevated to Administrator
3. cd to `D:\`
4. Run `LaunchBuildEnv.cmd`
5. cd to source tree (this branch builds with VS2019, SDK 19041, WDK 19041)
6. Run `msbuild /t:build /p:configuration=Release /p:platform=x64`

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\Use
  rs\me\Documents\src\soureroot\project\subproject\..\include /I"C:\Users\me\Documents\src\sourceroot\project\subproject\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows-static\include" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /D NDEBUG /D
   _LIB /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy /Qpar /fp:precise /Qspectre /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope
   /Zc:inline /std:c++17 /Fo"x64\Release\\" /Fd"x64\Release\subproject.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue SourceFile1.cpp
  
  SourceFile1.cpp
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\me\Documents\src\sourceroot\project\subproject
\subproject.vcxproj]
```

subproject is configured in Visual Studio to use Windows SDK version `10.0 (latest installed version)`.

What have I done wrong why the EWDK is not able to pickup fundamental headers from the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately answering my own question.

Since I have both SDK 19041 and SDK 22000 installed, using `10.0 (latest installed version` is selecting SDK 22000 with the EWDK 19041.

**[SOLUTION]** Retarget solution to use SDK matching the EWDK I'm using to build.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it will be helpful. Thanks for sharing the solution.